# load images from firebase, when i use the link of the images in firebase, it download the image and doesn't open it

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

load images from firebase, when i use the link of the images in firebase, it download the image and doesn't open it.

```
String productImage =
      'https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.a57e0ce54f0f136475a3ce0236cb7041?rik=jmc9cI1amG6uzA&pid=ImgRaw&r=0';

final DocumentSnapshot productsDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('products')
          .doc(widget.productId)
          .get();
      productTitle = productsDoc.get("title");
      productDescription = productsDoc.get("description");
      productPrice = productsDoc.get("price");
      productSalePrice = productsDoc.get("salePrice");
      productImage = productsDoc.get("imageUrl");
      productCategory = productsDoc.get("productCategoryName");
      isOnSale = productsDoc.get("isOnSale");
```

the link of images on firebase is saved like this:
[text](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/electronic-shop-f9524.appspot.com/o/productsImages%2F6c616f10-84d0-4711-8340-5630f415ae2c.jpg?alt=media&token=7f9edefb-41e5-40b8-8a9b-84d9b20562e9)

and when i import it and try to show
`Image.network( productImage, fit: BoxFit.fill, height: size.width * 0.12, ),`

i get errors

the rules of firebase

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if i run using this command flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
the images appear but only in the smallest window size and if they became bigger error fulll the terminal and they disappear